# How can I print a Decimal floating pointer in hexadecimal format (0xNNN.NNp+P) using Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex, precision

What I need to do is exactly like `float.hex` but for Decimal instead of float.
I'm using Decimal because I can't lose precision. Important: I need to print using this format (0xNNN.NNp+P). For example 0 is 0x0.0p+0.

Considering:

`d = Decimal(line)`

I have tried `hex(d)`, `d.hex()`, `Decimal.hex(d)` and nothing worked.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!